# Warn developer to call `super.foo()` in java

Tags: java, reflection

Lets say I have these two classes, one extending the other

```
public class Bar{

    public void foo(){

    }

}

public class FooBar extends Bar {

    @Override
    public void foo(){
        super.foo(); //<-- Line in question
    }

}
```

What I want to do is warn the user to call the super-class's method `foo` if they haven't in the override method, is this possible?

Or is there a way to know, using reflection that a method that overrides a method of its super-class calls the original method if I pass on the class type to the super?

for example:

```
public abstract class Bar{

    public Bar(Class<? extends Bar> cls){
        Object instance = getInstance();
        if (!instance.getClass().equals(cls)) {
            throw new EntityException("The instance given does not match the class given.");
    }
        //Find the method here if it has been overriden then throw an exception
        //If the super method isn't being called in that method
    }

    public abstract Object getInstance();

    public void foo(){

    }

}

public class FooBar extends Bar {

    public FooBar(){
        super(FooBar.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getInstance(){
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void foo(){
        super.foo();
    }

}
```

Maybe even an annotation I can put on the super method so it shows that it needs to be called?

---

**EDIT**

Note, its not the super class that needs to call the foo method, it would be someone calling the sub class's foo method, for example a database `close` method

I would even be happy with making the method "un-overrideable" if it came down to it, but would still like to give it a custom message.

---

**Edit 2**

This here is what I wanted in a way:

[image]

But it would still be nice to have the above, or even give them a custom message to do something else like, `Cannot override the final method from Bar, please call it from your implementation of the method instead`

Comment: This might be possible with a static code analysis tool / rule checker (e.g. IDEA). It should likely not be done at runtime (e.g. with reflection).

Comment: If you can't use the template pattern, FindBugs has an annotation that detects missing overrides: [OverrideMustInvoke](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html)

Comment: *I would even be happy with making the method "un-overrideable"*: that's what `final` is for.

Comment: I'd say that doing something like this is a matter of poor design. Normally such things, if needed, are handled via Javadoc. If you want the user to call db.close() method, just let him make a separate call to it after work with db is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: To answer the edited, question, which includes:

> I would even be happy with making the method "un-overrideable"

... just make the method `final`. That will prevent subclasses from overriding it. From [section 8.4.3.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3):

> A method can be declared `final` to prevent subclasses from overriding or hiding it.
>
> It is a compile-time error to attempt to override or hide a `final` method.

To answer the original question, consider using the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) instead:

```
public abstract class Bar {
    public foo() {
        // Do unconditional things...
        ...
        // Now subclass-specific things
        fooImpl();
    }

    protected void fooImpl();
}

public class FooBar extends Bar {
    @Override protected void fooImpl() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That doesn't force subclasses of `FooBar` to override `fooImpl` and call `super.fooImpl()` of course - but `FooBar` *could* do this by applying the same pattern again - making its own `fooImpl` implementation final, and introducing a new protected abstract method.

Comment: @SmartLemon: Well yes, if you completely change the requirements, `final` would indeed do it...

Comment: Sorry, check out the second edit, the original is still part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is something like following

```
public class Bar{

    public final void foo(){
        //do mandatory stuff
        customizeFoo();
    }

    public void customizeFoo(){

    }

}

public class FooBar extends Bar {

    @Override
    public void customizeFoo(){
        //do custom suff
    }

}
```

foo method made 'final' in superclass so that subclasses can't override and avoid doing mandatory stuff